# Reference to addValue is ambiguous

Tags: java

I am using jFreeChart to create a line chart. When I changed the variables, it gave me an error saying the reference is ambiguous. How can I fix this?

x and y are int and eq is String

```
private DefaultCategoryDataset createDataset() {
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset( );
        for(short i = 0; i < 200; i++){
            dataset.addValue(x[i] , eq, y[i]);
    }
    return dataset;
}
```

Comment: What are the types of `x` and `y`?

Comment: Right - so which overload do you *want* it to call? It's valid for both `addValue(double, Comparable, Comparable)` and `addValue(Number, Comparable, Comparable)`. Just casting `x[i]` to either `double` or `Number` should fix the problem...

Comment: Probably unrelated to the problem, but there's no reason for `i` to be `short` instead of `int`. Those two extra bytes you'd consume will be freed up at the end of the `for` loop.

Comment: (@jsheeran) AFAIK there are no two extra bytes - a local `short`variable consumes the same memory as an `int` one . Even a `boolean`  would use the 4 bytes on the stack, only `long` and `double` use more. (reference implementation)